Solana CLI not updating PATH, new terminal window not recognizing Solana CLI
In a nut shell:
I install Solana CLI, get prompted to update PATH, I do so, confirm solana is installed with solana --version and then close terminal, open new terminal window and try Solana --version and receive zsh: command not found.
For a more detailed explanation:
I start with:
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"
Solana CLI installs and says:
Please update your PATH environment variable to include the solana programs:
PATH="/Users/matt/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
So I attempt
export PATH="/Users/matt/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
Then try
echo $Path
and receive:
/Users/matt/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin
then try Solana --version
solana-cli 1.17.25 (src:d0ed878d; feat:3580551090, client:SolanaLabs)
So thinking I'm good to go I open a new terminal window and run Solana --version
and cant escape from this zsh: command not found: solana
then I try echo $PATH:
it says:
/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/matt/.cargo/bin
something is not sticking. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

You'll need to add the export PATH="/Users/matt/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH" line somewhere in your ~/.zshrc.
More information about adding to your path at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh

Thank you that was the solution! I'm a newb to this if you cant tell. added export PATH="/Users/matt/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH" to .zshrc file. restarted terminal, entered % solana --version and boom =
solana-cli 1.17.25 (src:d0ed878d; feat:3580551090, client:SolanaLabs) Thank you!!!
